# how to connect function between two classes

Tags: c++, qt, class, connection, qt5

I have two different class in two files:

```
class Game: public QGraphicsView()

class Window: public QMainWindow()
{
 public: Window(); 
              Game *game;

 public slots: void test() {game = new Game();};
}
```

in `Window.cpp` I start a new Game using test() function:

```
Window::Window() {test();}
```

now in `Game.cpp` I create a `QMessageBox` with two `QPushButton`

```
    QMessageBox *box= new QMessageBox();

    QPushButton *btYES = box->addButton(tr("YES"),QMessageBox::ActionRole);
    QPushButton *btNO = box->addButton(tr("NO"),QMessageBox::ActionRole);

    box->exec();

    if (box->clickedButton() == btYES) {Window::test();}
    if (box->clickedButton() == btNO) {close();}
```

As you can see I want to connect the function `test()` to `btYES` inside the `Game.cpp` but that function is inside `Window.cpp` and its function is to start a new game.

It is possible to do so?

Comment: Seems like you want to create `static` function. If yes, then this is the solution: `static void test(){/*...*/}`

Comment: `Window::Window() {Game *game = new Game();}` <= You create a new local variable called  `game`.  `void test() {game = new Game();};` <= You initialize a member variable called `game`. Looks potentially dangerous, is this on purpose?

Comment: Ok sorry I Made a mistake. I declared {Game *game} in the class Window.h in public:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

QPushButton emits events when it its pressed/released

So you could connect the, lets say, released signal to a slot:

```
connect(button, SIGNAL(released()), windowClass, SLOT(handleButton()));
```

In your case you need to send it across classes, so you may need to do it in two steps.

In game:

```
// connect the button to a local slot
connect(btYES, SIGNAL(released()), this, SLOT(handleYesButton()));

// in the slot emit a signal - declare the signal in the header
game::handleYesButton()
{
   emit userChoiceYes();
}
```

In window

```
// connect the signal in game to a your slot:
connect(game, SIGNAL(userChoiceYes()), this, SLOT(test()));
```

Then when btnYes is pressed/released the signal released is emitted - you pick that up in handleYesButton() and emit your own signal which your window class is connected to and handles it in test()

Answer (score 0):

Based on @code_fodder answer, but you don't even need another slot, plus the basic signal for a QPushButton is `clicked()`. Here's the [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractbutton.html#clicked) :

> A push button emits the signal clicked() when it is activated by the
>   mouse, the Spacebar or by a keyboard shortcut. **Connect to this signal
>   to perform the button's action**. Push buttons also provide **less
>   commonly used signals**, for example **pressed()** and **released()**.

To start, instead of adding another slot in your class `Game`, **just connect the button's signal `clicked()` to another signal** :

```
connect(btYES, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SIGNAL(btYesClicked()));
```

The signal from the class `Game` is now emitted when you press the button `btYes`. Now, you just have to **connect this signal to a slot `test()` in your class `Window`** :

```
connect(game, SIGNAL(btYesClicked()), this, SLOT(test()));
```